# How to create an inline div with same height and alignment as inline input?

Tags: css, input, cross-browser, alignment, height

I am currently trying to create something like this:[image]

Where there is a div(with a checkbox and label) to the right side of an input, properly aligned and with the same height (so it looks like 1 whole box).

Here is a JSfiddle with my code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/asfo3u97/3/

Currently, I am unable to get this to look the same cross browser. In Firefox, the JSfiddle example above looks fine (everything is aligned and is the same height). However, in Chrome, the div to the rightside is not properly aligned. Same with iOS

Comment: And what's your relevant minimal HTML?

Comment: I think what David tried to tell you is, that your question is missing the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Best would be to create a http://fiddle.jshell.net/ for your problem.

Comment: I am going to take a punt here, it is missing display: inline-block and float:left;

Answer (score 0):

Final solution, using display:table-cell and display:table-row, without extra padding for the side div
http://fiddle.jshell.net/asfo3u97/8/